# How to wait till one subscribe completes execution & contine for next item inside a foreach loop in angular 7

Tags: angular, rxjs, frontend

i have a service call which returns a observable inside a foreach.

How do i make service call to wait till one call excutes completely before continuing to next index.

```
this.deleteNodes.foreach(node => {
  this.Service.deleteNode(node.id).subscribe((response) => {  // returns a observable 
     count--;
   }, (error => {
       count--;
  }));
}
```

I wanna make the service call one after the other.

I'm just decrementing the count variable after each successful call so that if count == 0, i'll show a UI toast message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`concatMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/concatmap.html) is probably what you're looking for. You'll need to convert your `this.deleteNodes` into an observable (via [`from`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/from.html)) so your logic will probably look something like this:

```
from(this.deleteNodes).pipe(
  concatMap((node) => this.Service.deleteNode(node.id)),
);
```

It's not totally clear what the `count--` is doing in your code sample, but can edit the above to take it into account if you can explain it a little bit more.

Comment: Count is a variable i'm using to dcrement after each successful call & if count == 0 @ last i need to show a UI toats message.

Comment: You can show it using `finalize` operator after concatMap. Will fire once all requests are done